# text underline - createLabel

Tags: ios, label, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, underline

i am trying to make a text with underline, but i am receiving this warning.

Screenshot [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s36/sh/2666b0ca-425f-4f8a-ae23-9b4cafccca37/36af469a1f40fb95) !

The code is:

```
 var texto= L("txt_olvide_password");
 var attr = Titanium.UI.createAttributedString({ 
     text: texto, 
     attributes: [ { type: Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINES_STYLE, range: [0,texto.length] }, ]
 }); 
 var lblOlvidePassword = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
     top: '58%',
     color: clr_aux1,
     font: { fontFamily: font_primaria, fontSize: 16 },
     attributedString: attr
 });
 vistaLogin.add(lblOlvidePassword)
```

What am i doing wrong ?
thanks in advance.

Titanium Appcelerador 4.5.0
SDK: 5.2.0
iOS / Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With underline you should also use

`value` like

```
var attr = Titanium.UI.createAttributedString({ 
    text : texto, 
    attributes : [{ 
        type : Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINES_STYLE, 
        range : [0,texto.length],
        value : Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_STYLE_SINGLE
    }]
});
```

and now its working.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Ti.UI.ATTIBUTE_UNDERLINES_STYLE` you must set a value : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Attribute-property-value with one these constants :

```
Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_STYLE_NONE
Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_STYLE_SINGLE
Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_STYLE_THICK
Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_STYLE_DOUBLE
Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_PATTERN_SOLID
Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_PATTERN_DOT
Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_PATTERN_DASH
Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_PATTERN_DASH_DOT
Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_PATTERN_DASH_DOT_DOT
Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_BY_WORD
```